# Can anyone explain line number 3 of this code?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain line number 3 ?

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var converted = str.replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(char) { 
        return (char === 'z' || char === 'Z') ? 'a' : String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt() + 1);
    });

    return converted;
}
```

Comment: What about it specifically? There's quite a lot packed into that line. Do you understand how a ternary works?

Comment: This is some kind of [Caesar Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher), where each letter is replaced by the letter following letter in the alphabet.

Comment: With the exception that the lower- and uppercase `z` both are "translated" to a lowercase `a`. For the rest of the alphabet the case is preserved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function LetterChanges(str) {
    var converted = str.replace(/[a-z]/gi, function(char) { 
        return (char === 'z' || char === 'Z') ? 'a' : String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt() + 1);
    });

    return converted;
}
```

In a nutshell `LetterChanges` will take in a string and will convert all the letters (`chars`) in the string to the next letter (`char`) that follows it in the alphabet. Unless that `char` is `z` or`Z`. It will link it back to `a`.

The anonymous function here:

```
function(char) {
    return (char === 'z' || char === 'Z') ? 'a' : String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt() + 1);
}
```

is ran on **every** char in the string and can be written as

```
function(char) {
    if(char === 'z' || char ==='Z') {
        char = 'a';
    } else {
        char = char.charCodeAt() + 1;
    }    
    return char;
}
```

Specifically, line number 3 is: **If `char` is an uppercase or lowercase `z` `(char === 'z' || char ==='Z')` then make it an `a` (`? 'a'`), else make `char` the next letter in the alphabet. (`: String.fromCharCode(char.charCodeAt() + 1)`)**

Answer (score 1):

if the letter is z or Z, it returns 'a', otherwise, it returns the next letter in the alphabet.

Comment: Interesting to note is also the fact that this happens in an anonymous function that is called once for each letter in the variable str that is passed to the LetterChanges function.